# Automatic actions when creating a new NSManagedObject

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have two entities - A and B. A includes a set of Bs. Every time I create a B, I want to make sure I add it to a special instance of A.

Looking at the NSManagedObjectClass reference, it is very clear that I should NOT be overriding the init method. So where is the best place to "catch" the creation of B? The only way I can see is to use validateForInsert, but I'm concerned that that's not really what it's meant for, and thus may cause headaches down the road. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [NSManagedObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) documentation:

> awakeFromInsert
>   Invoked automatically by the Core Data framework when the receiver is first inserted into a managed object context.

Subclass this method on your entity's class.